# SQLServer Issue with view on another database

Tags: sql-server, privileges

SQLServer 2008R2, we have the following architecture:

Table A (on Database A)  <-- View A (on Database B, same server)

Users should be able to select View A but not Table A. The Scenario works fine, if table and view reside on the same database. But with the given architekture, View A can only be selected, if Table A can be selected as well.

Can we solve that without changing the "concept of different databases"?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to turn on the `DB_CHAINING` database option in both databases. This will allow normal ownership chaining to extend to both databases as long as the referenced table owners map to the same login. In the case of dbo-owned objects, the implication is that both databases must be owned by the same login (AUTOORIZATION). Users must exist in both databases and have permissions on the view. Permissions on the tables referenced by the view are not necessary.